# Laravel: get users with multiple educations by education level

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have default laravel `users` table and my custom `educations` table in my database. In `educations` table users can save education histories.

Example `educations` data:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
id | user_id | university | speciality | finish_year | level
------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |   16    |   Boston   |  Developer |    2018     |   4 
------------------------------------------------------------
 2 |   10    |   Sinergy  |   Designer |    2014     |   4 
------------------------------------------------------------
 9 |   16    |   Sinergy  |  Economist |    2010     |   8 
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now how I can get users using laravel eloquent by education level?

For example get users where education level == 4

Comment: [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/eloquent-nested-relations-with-where-clause) can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you have a `educations` method in your User model that represents a `HasMany` association, you can use eloquent's `has` (or `whereHas`) method:

```
$users = App\User::whereHas('educations', function ($query) {
    $query->where('level', 4);
})->get();
```

Here's a link to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the relationship setup correctly, so in your `User` model you should have something like this:

```
public function educations() {
    return $this->hasMany(Education::class);
}
```

Then a simple use will be the following:

```
User::with(['educations' => function($query) {
    $query->where('level', 4);
}])->get()->filter(function($user) {
    return $user->educations->count() > 0;
});
```

The opposite approach would be:

```
Education::with('user')->where('level', 4)->get();
```

This will give you list of educations where the level is 4, and for each the user assigned to it.

Comment: Yes, I have correct relationship. Now I'll try your answer code @nakov. Thanks!

Comment: this code not work for me. When I run query return all users instead of users with custom level.

Comment: @AndreasHunter yes, it will return all the users but will return their educations if the level is 4. So you can filter them afterwards look at my edited answer now. If the educations collection contains any item it will return. 

The other way around will be to get all the users through the Education, but I don't think that that's a good approach. If you want I can give you that example too.

Comment: Give me your second example variant please and say me what is the best practice in laravel for my task @nakov?

Comment: @AndreasHunter I updated my answer. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. So both are good examples, but I would go with the first one, so you will get list of Users instead of list of educations.

Comment: @nakov The problem with the first solution is that you get all users even if it does not have level 4 education. The second (opposite approach) should perform better :)

Comment: @AndreasHunter, LucasFerreira gave a much better answer. So you should go with that.

Comment: @LucasFerreira yes, but then I filter to return just those. Your answer is much better anyway.